# Error in my jquery Code `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'eq' of null`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please mention the error in this code.

`$("#gridTable tr").eq(1).find('td').forEach( function(){//some code here});`

I have tried different selectors but nothing worked.

I also tried using just id of specific row but same error with message that:

> `Cannot call method find of null`.

On:

```
$("#firstRow").find('td').forEach( function(){//some code here});
```

Comment: `$("#gridTable tr:eq(1)").find('td').forEach( function(){//some code here});`. Try using this

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal same problem again. If this is some type of library issue or something else then plz mention.

Comment: Show us the rendered HTML

Comment: @SalmanA how to know. This is my include statement        `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`                  And this file is present in the mentioned directory.

Comment: @A.M: Go to your page, and open the console. If you don't see any errors, then that script load worked. Then in the console, type this: `jQuery === $` and press Enter. My guess is it'll say `false`. Something you're loading after jQuery is taking over the `$` symbol.

Comment: problem solved by replacing `$` with `JQuery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each case, the error is telling you that `$("#gridTable tr")` returned `null`.

This suggests you're not using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), but instead [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) or [MooTools](http://mootools.net) (or something else entirely). jQuery's `$()` function will never return `null`, but both Prototype and MooTools' `$()` function will, if they don't find an element with the given ID. If you're using Prototype or MooTools, note that `$()` doesn't take a *selector* like jQuery's does, it takes an **`id`**. So you wouldn't use the `#` on it, and couldn't pass in a descendant combinator as you are in your example. (The nearest equivalent in Prototype to jQuery's `$` is `$$`.)

---

Separately, if you were using jQuery, jQuery objects don't have `forEach`; they do have [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) which is similar (but the order of the arguments to your iterator function is different).

Comment: I agree with your answer but the fact is error occurs before the `forEach` loop comes into execution and whether the function is `each` or `forEach`, that function is not executed. And I am using jquery.     `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>` this is the statement to include jquery file

Comment: @A.M: The `forEach` thing is secondary, because as you say, it's not getting that far. Again: jQuery's `$()` will never return `null`, and yet the `$()` you're calling is returning `null`. Therefore, it is not jQuery's. Look to see what scripts you're loading **after** jQuery, one of them apparently takes over the `$()` function. (If you need to keep using that other script, you can use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` for jQuery's function.)

Comment: thanx and problem solved by replacing $ with JQuery.